# Pointer Typecasting: int to short in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary, typecasting-operator

I expect the output to be 131200 (2^17 + 2^ 7) rather than 2. Makes sense in theory, but it is not working.
The bit pattern of arr[3] after the pointer typecasting line would be something like - [00000000 00000010 00000000 10000000]. (Please tell me if I am wrong somewhere.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr[5];
    arr[3] = 128;
    ((short *) arr)[6] = 2;
    printf("%i\n", arr[3]);
}
```

Comment: And if you do `printf("short: %d, int: %d\r\n", (int)sizeof(short), (int)sizeof(int));`?

Comment: `((short *) arr)[6] = 2;` is [a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), undefined behavior, and a good way to get a `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` on hardware that has alignment restrictions.

Comment: Why expect `2^9` and not `2^16 * 2` as `short` is commonly 16 bit.

Comment: Have you tried `((short *) arr)[6 + 1] = 2;`?

Comment: yea, that works!

Comment: This also won't work on a big-endian machine.

Comment: but why at an offset of 7 from base address? @chux

Comment: Make a diagram on paper, and appreciate the endianness.

Comment: @sudo chux comment is little-endian, but the code is for big-endian, so it overwrites the earlier value.

Comment: @HarrySandhu,  Research [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)